# Does Vala have typedefs?

Tags: typedef, vala

Does Vala have some capability to do something similar to `typedef` in C or `alias` in D? I've checked its sporadic documentation, and couldn't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a `typedef` as such, but you can extend most types, including the primitives:

```
public struct foo : int8 { }
```

This will generate a `typedef` in the generated C, but, strictly speaking, it isn't one in Vala because it isn't a type alias (i.e., `int8` and `foo` are not automatically interconvertible).

This doesn't work for delegates.